# Snowflake views

Tags: view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a view as below.

`Create or replace view test as`

`With a as (`

`Select * from tblX )`

`B as (`

`Select * from thlY )`

`Select a.name , b.product`

`From a left join b on`

`a.Id = b.Id`

Is it possible to get the value of either a or b from the above view? And if yes, how?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "value"? Since A and B are table expressions, they don't have scalar values. Do you mean get the rows from that table expressions A and B in the view? If so, then not directly, no. It would require separate definitions.

Answer (score 1):

CTEs are ephemeral views where as the create view statement is a permanent view. So if you don't want a or b in the output then don't include it.